# Domain of $(x+1)\log(1+x+2\sin^2(x))$

Tags: functions

I am trying to find the domain of:$$(x+1)\log(1+x+2\sin^2(x))$$

I set $$1 + x + 2\sin^2(x) > 0$$
I see that: $$ 1 + x > 0 > -2\sin^2(x) $$
So I am fine for $$x > -1$$
However I see that for small x, such as $x = -5$ my x is out of the domain. I then set $\phi(x) = 1 + x + 2\sin^2(x)$ and I calculate the derivative:
$$ \phi'(x) = 1 + 2(2\sin(x)\cos(x)) = 1+2\sin(2x) $$ and I find the points such that $\phi'(x) > 0$ but after that I am stuck and I do not know how to go on. Any tips?

Comment: How do you get from the *single* inequality $1+x+2\sin^2x\gt0$ to *two* inequalities, $1+x\gt0$ and $0\gt-2\sin^2x$?

Comment: Mmm I was just trying to select an interval which satisfied the condition

Answer (score 1):

You have got the right idea. However, the problem is that you have $1 + x > -2 \sin^2 x$. Since the LHS has a linear term, and the RHS is trigonometric, the root has no closed form.

Your best bet is to find an approximation of the root. You can apply the derivative you have calculated to [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Improving your approximation of $x = -1$, since $2 \sin^2 -\frac{3\pi}{4} = 1$, and $1 + -\frac{3\pi }{4} \approx -1.36$, we can start with a first approximation of $x = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$:

$$x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$
$$= -\frac{3 \pi}{4} - \frac{f(-\frac{3\pi}{4})}{f'(-\frac{3\pi}{4})}$$
$$\approx -\frac{3 \pi}{4} - \frac{-0.356194490192}{3}$$
$$\approx −2.23746299346$$

You can iterate this process several more times to get a more accurate answer.

The reason we chose $x = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$ was because $f'(-1) = 1 + 2 \sin(-2) > 0$, so the function is decreasing around $x=-1$. However, the tangent would give a *positive* first approximation of the root, which is definitely not accurate. $f'(-\frac{3\pi}{4}) < 0$ so the approximation will be more accurate.

Comment: Mmm what if I want to find the exact solution? Following my method with the derivative?

Comment: You can't. As I said before the solution is transcendental.

Comment: Besides, where is this question from?

Comment: Mmm ok, it's from an old Analysis exam at my University.

Comment: I mean I would love to use some theorems with the derivative of $\phi$ to say that it exists an $x_0$ such that $(x_0,\infty)$ is the domain without actually finding the $x_0$, is that possible?

Comment: Well the derivative has a maximum at $x = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Since the function is increasing between $x = -\frac{3\pi}{4}$ at $x = -\frac{5\pi}{12}$, there must be a root in between. Furthermore, since in the interval the function is concave down, the  gradient is decreasing, so for any $a$ between $ -\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to the root, the zero lies between the zero of the tangent of $a$ and infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an almost exact solution of the equation
$$1 + x + 2\sin^2(x) = 0$$ using a $[1,n]$ Padé approximant built at $x=-\frac{3\pi}4$ as Toby Mak showed.

This would give
$$x_{(0)}=x_{(1)}=-\frac{3\pi}4+\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{2}{3}\right)\approx -2.23746$$
$$x_{(2)}=-\frac{3\pi}4+\left(\frac{27 (3 \pi -8)}{260+48 \pi -9 \pi ^2} \right)\approx -2.23671$$
$$x_{(3)}=-\frac{3\pi}4+\left(\frac{2080-396 \pi -216 \pi ^2+27 \pi ^3}{24 \left(-98-48 \pi +9 \pi ^2\right)} \right)\approx -2.23671$$